# nodejs: npm global package too many download

Tags: node.js, npm

I create a little program using commander to generate a small application schema.

I use ncp to copy my file into the new directory, that working perfectly, the package is only for global installation, no other module dependent on this one. The problem is that I get 4730 download for the last but I only download this 2 or 3 time.

```
var  program = require('commander')
, pkg = require('../package.json')
, version = pkg.version
, create_project = require('./create_project')
, create_bundle = require('./create_bundle')
, create_entities = require('./create_entities')
;

// commander

program
 .version(version)
 .option('-f, --force', 'force on non-empty directory')

program
 .command('create:project <name>')
 .description('create a new project')
 .action(function(name){
    create_project.do(name);
 })
;
program
 .command('create:bundle <name>')
 .description('create a new bundle in your project')
 .action(function(name){
    create_bundle.do(name);
 })
;
program
 .command('create:database')
 .description('create the database --- note : you need first to update your config/db.js file')
 .action(function(){
    create_entities.database();
 })
;
program
 .command('entity:update <name>')
 .description('update entity <name> ')
 .action(function(name){
    create_entities.do(name);
 })
;

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Comment: it might fall into a loop that call for installing the same packages, or its doing a update on npm cache, try purging the cache, doublecheck the package json of your script and rerun.

Comment: I already checked my script, and my package.json, no problem there. I just clean the cache, and forget to make npm cache ls, to see if problem was from here. I will see tomorrow. Thanks